# Check for specific letter in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to check if the first letter in a string is l, the l can be upper or lower case, if it is an l I want to trim it from the string and I am currently  using this code to do it

```
String firstLetter = result.Text[0].ToString();
if (result.Text.Length == 18)
{
    if (firstLetter.Equals("l".ToString()) || firstLetter.Equals("L".ToString()))
    {
        result.Text.Remove(0, 1);
    }
    if (firstLetter == "l" || firstLetter == "L" || firstLetter == "1")
    {
        result.Text.Remove(0, 1);
    }
    if (result.Text.StartsWith("l".ToString()) || result.Text.ToUpper().StartsWith("L".ToString()))
    {
           result.Text.Remove(0, 1);
    }
}
```

none of these if statements have worked, they are completely skipped over, why arent they working?

Comment: Is the first condition (`result.Text.Length == 18`) skipped over?

Comment: What object is result?  Is it a Textbox?

Comment: @H.Moody That's not correct.  Comparing strings with the equals `==` operator doesn't compare by reference.

Comment: @H.Moody Actually in C# `==` is overloaded to work as `Equals()`.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Sorry buddy i forgot that's not Java :-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
result = result.TrimStart({'L', 'l'});
```

This will take "Llama" and make it "ama". If you are trying to take "Llama" and get "lama", use this code:

```
result = result.ToUpper().StartsWith("L") ? result.Remove(0,1) : result;
```

Comment: Will that not trim all instances of the character and not just the first?

Comment: @TrevorElliott - No, it will trim it only from the beginning of the string, which is what he wants (looking at his `.Remove(0,1)` statement)

Comment: From MSDN: "Removes all leading occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object."

Comment: @TrevorElliott -- Keyword "leading"..Only Leading occurrences

Comment: I assume if there are two L's as in "LLsomething" he wants it to come out as "Lsomething" but I guess that's up to him to confirm.

Comment: @TrevorElliott - Oh I do see your point...I will update my answer

Comment: You can remove this part from the solution, it will never be true: result.ToUpper().StartsWith("l")

Comment: will this turn the entire string to uppercase?

Comment: @CamConnor no it won't, strings are immutable. See my answer for an explanation *why* your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If your .Text[] isn't exaclty 18 then it won't go in there.

Once you get the text out of whatever your result is just do this.

```
if (firstLetter.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() == "L")
        {
            // equals l so lets remove it
            firstLetter = firstLetter.Remove(0, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
bool isFirstL = firstLetter.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper().Equals("L");
```

And you can use this expression in the way you want, not to assign value for bool.

BTW. you have line `if (result.Text.Length == 18)` does your string really contains 18 characters?

Comment: it is a check, the string should only have 17 but sometimes an l is added making it 18 that is why I want to remove it

Answer (score 1):

I had to do:

```
result = result.TrimStart(new char[] {'L', 'l'});
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# the string type is designed to be immutable, meaning that you cannot change a string instance. This is from the [documentation of the Remove method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx), emphasis mine:

> Returns **a new string** in which a specified number of characters in the current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.

So to actually see the result of the call to Remove, you will have to assign it to something, for example:

```
result.Text = result.Text.Remove(0, 1);
```

To see if the string starts with an L, the cleanest way would be to use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx). The entire code would like this:

```
if (result.Text.Length == 18 &&
    result.Text.StartsWith("L", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    result.Text = result.Text.Remove(0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `string.IndexOf`, which takes `IgnoreCase` parameter, like:

```
string firstLetter = "LlSomething";
if (firstLetter.IndexOf("l", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0 
        && firstLetter.Length > 0)
{
    firstLetter = firstLetter.Substring(1);
}
```

and you will get `lSomething` as the output.